# How to install ifxpy module in docker image python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, docker, informix

Hi have created a docker image with base image python3.6

I have installed ifxpy using "pip install ifxpy" and after successful build ifxpy-3.0.1 I tried to import ifxpy lib and it gives me the error

Successfully built flask-jwt idna-ssl
Installing collected packages: click,
ifxpy-3.0.1 itsdangerous-1.1.0 multidict-4.5.2 pytz-2019.1 requests-2.22.0 schedule-0.6.0 typing-extensions-3.7.4 urllib3-1.25.3 yarl-1.3.0

Error logs from docker :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pythonuser/Informix_Conn.py", line 3, in <module>
    import IfxPyDbi as dbapi2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IfxPyDbi.py", line 43, in <module>
    import IfxPy
ImportError: libifdmr.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: 'libifdmr.so' is one of the libraries included in CSDK, so you need to have that installed in your image before you can install IfxPy

Comment: Thanks for reply!!

I have successfully installed CSDK in linux machine and set all the path still i got the below error after trying to connect to db

Exception('[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Unspecified System Error =  -23101. SQLCODE=-23101')

Comment: ok, at least that's progress ;).  23101 is normally caused due not having INFORMIXDIR set in the environment. The ODBC driver needs to load some files (e.g. language/messages) from $INFORMIXDIR. Try setting that somewhere in the environment. You will also need LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to $INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/cli. so the rest of libraries are properly loaded.

Comment: Thanks @jsagera for helping me out to all the queries we have resolved our problem by setting up environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

`libifdmr.so` is a library of the Informix Client SDK.

So first install the Informix Client SDK. Furthermore you have to set the enviroment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/cli`.